# Эмуляция нажатия клавиши в окне

Tags: c#, c++

Необходимо на C# захватить окно и когда оно активно, нажимать, например, пробел. Как реализовать?
Или может есть WinAPI функции для этого? Можно и на C++.

Comment: Я как обычно. Искал - не нашел. Задал вопрос. Поискал еще - нашел. Потом прочитал ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отслеживание активаций окон делается [хуками CBT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx) (computer-based training), а точнее HCBT_ACTIVATE. Для того, чтобы добавить хуки в приложение .NET, нужно писать отдельную DLL, которая будет отслеживать хуки и посылать сообщения в приложение по получении оного. Это отдельная задача.

После того, как окно стало активным, есть несколько способов послать пробел:

1. [Класс SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)
2. [Функция SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. [Функция SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) c WM_CHAR

Функции API использовать через Platform Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

Захватывать события функцией [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), посылать событие [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950).
[About Messages and Message Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927#system_defined)