# Как послать клавишу в окно браузера на страницу

Tags: c#

Получаю активное окно страницы куда нужно отправлять клавишу №1

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

public static class FindBadooWindow
{
  public static string GetActiveWindowTitle()
  {
    string strTitle = string.Empty;
    try
    {
       var handle = GetForegroundWindow();
       int intLength = GetWindowTextLength(handle) + 1;
       var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(intLength);
       if (GetWindowText(handle, stringBuilder, intLength) > 0)
       {
          strTitle = stringBuilder.ToString();
       }
    }
    catch { }
    return strTitle;
  }
}
```

Активное окно называется: Badoo - Знакомства

Проверку делаю так:

```
if (FindBadooWindow.GetActiveWindowTitle().Contains("Badoo - Знакомства"))
```

Как отправить клавишу в окно в цикле?

Comment: Чем вам Selenium не угодил?

Comment: @tym32167, Selenium - Никогда не работал с ним

Comment: ну вот например, нажмете вы клавишу, страничка начнет что то грузить, как вы поймете, это она догрузилась? У меня просто ощущение, что вы изобретаете велосипед.

Comment: Win32 Api метод есть `keybd_event` и более новый `SendInput`, эмулируют нажатия на клавиши. То естб ввод будет только в активное окно, как с клавиатуры.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Эмуляция нажатия клавиши в окне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35387/%d0%ad%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b5)